# what is a proper api uri version format?

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I inherited an API in development from a previous developer which uses the following API uri pattern for versioning:

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/

Is this the proper format for API versioning? For example, if a client wants v2 of the User API then the following uri format would appear to indicate that a v2 of the API exists for users but not necessarily that a v2 of the API exists for all entities:

http://localhost:8080/api/users/v2

So it seems like the second uri would be more granular. Is one of these patterns more correct or more commonly used than the other?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the former: `/api/v1/users/` because:

- If the new version of the API is exposed as a separate instance of a web-application then configuring site-wide routing is a lot easier: just route all requests after `/api/v1/...` to the old version and `/api/v2/...` to the new version. If the `v2` is at the end of the URI then configuring routing will be a pain.
- The new version of the API may render higher levels obsolete, what if "users" were replaced with "identities", for example? Then the "v2" suffix becomes meaningless.
- Resource paths are hierarchies - having a version indicator after a resource should be used to refer to a version *of that resource*, e.g. if you wanted to get the 2nd snapshot of `User 123`'s state, then that might be `/api/users/123/v2` and to get the 300th snapshot then `/api/users/123/v300` - by putting the API version information there makes this unclear.
- Resource paths should go from left-to-right in "least-to-most specific" order. The API version at the end messes-up that logical order.
- Similarly, it makes sense that `/api/v1/users` represents "Users under Version 1 of the API" - instead of `/api/users/v1` in which case it becomes unclear ("Version 1 users of the API"? "A user named 'v1' under the API?", etc).

There are other approaches to consider: if your versioning is only concerned with different *schema versions* of your DTOs while the underlying data and business logic remains the same then you could let clients specify the DTO schema version they want in a querystring value:

```
GET /api/users/123?dtoVersion=1
GET /api/users/123?dtoVersion=2
```